# Merge/retag [tag:licensing] and [tag:licenses]?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

The tags [licensing](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/licensing) and [licenses](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/licenses) have the same sorts of questions. Should we make a synonym between the two, and/or clearly define distinct meanings (like "[licenses](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/licenses) is about government-issued licenses, while [licensing](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/licensing) is about things like IP licenses")?

Comment: I vote for the separate uses you indicate.  Amusingly, _you_ are presently the only active non-moderator with enough rep to create a synonym anyway!